# How do I restrict the clients that can access my Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Given that I create an Azure 'App Service'

How do I ensure that this service is only callable from ...

A.> 2 existing external servers (whose IP addresses will be known)

B.> 3 other App Services which I will be creating, but whose IP Addresses may not be known since I may need to scale those out (Over multiple additional instances)

To clarify... Is there some Azure service that will allow me to treat this collective of machines (both real and virtual) as a single group, such that I can apply some test on incoming requests to see if they originate from this group?

Comment: Votes to close are unhelpful without some suggestion of why the current phrasing of the question is inadequate. If suggestions were offered the question could be improved.

Answer (score 2):

on Azure WebApps, You may wish to know; the IP Restrictions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) allow you to define a list of IP addresses that are allowed to access your app. The allow list can include individual IP addresses or a range of IP addresses defined by a subnet mask. When a request to the app is generated from a client, the IP address is evaluated against the allow list. If the IP address is not in the list, the app replies with an HTTP 403 status code.

You can use IP and Domain Restrictions to control the set of IP addresses, and address ranges, that are either allowed or denied access to in your websites. With Azure WebApps you can enable/disable the feature, as well as customize its behavior, using web.config files located in their website.

Additionally, VNET Integration gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but does not grant private access to your web app from the virtual network. Private site access is only available with an ASE configured with an Internal Load Balancer (ILB).
If you haven’t checked this already, checkout Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network for more details on VNET Integration (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest dropping the whole what's my IP approach and throwing in OAuth. Azure AD gives you access tokens with moderate effort —

[Service to service calls using client credentials (shared secret or certificate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service)

Else, TLS client authentication would be next on my list. Although that tends to really suck if you have to deal with several programming stacks, TLS offloaders and what not.